# Python Sklearn: My project svm.SVC output error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, svm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvD1p.png)

### info:
use jupyter notbook
use sklearn.svm
error output fit

mycode:

from sklearn import svm
model = svm.SVC()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

--

Console output: [SVC()]

Comment: Please add more details on the problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you haven't shown (even in your image) an error

Comment: Run Jupyter
Code Python
Error (Sklearn fit)
output error (Console output: [SVC()]) 
 
Project extracted execution doesn't work (it doesn't give anything output of extracted )